# Date that the contest ends

Tags: discussion, contest

I hoped I wouldn't have to ask this, but after the sudden 0.9 release, it might be good to confirm...

Will there be at least a week's notice (preferably 2) given of the contest ending?

The application I am writing isn't large but it is in a language I have never really used before and I have other real life commitments. It would be annoying to have a few minor teaks left to make but to wake up and find that the contest has ended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be some lead time on the 0.9 -> 1.0 transition, and after *that* transition the contest end date will be publicized*.  There will be at least 1 week between the announcement of the end date, and the end date itself.

<sub>*Not necessarily immediately after, but the important part is **not before**.</sub>

Comment: So about 6-8 weeks then?

Answer (score 4):

> Your app must work against the final, 1.0 released version of the API. We’ll give you at least week’s notice here on the blog when that’s closer to happening.

That was from the blog post announcing the contest.  So it looks like we'll get about a week's notice :)